Fuzziness AUTO doesn't give desired results
I am using fuzzy logic in elastic search to search for similar names in the watchlist.
I am trying
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "column1": {
        "value": "wiiamjos",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}

enter image description here
inorder to get "WilliamJones" but it is giving nothing.
So, how can I adjust my query inorder to get desired results.
Although, it is working on AUTO when I am giving "wiiamjones", but I want to give some less alphabets inorder to match using fuzzy queries.

The code needs to be posted as text, not as a screenshot.

{
"query": {
"fuzzy": {
"column1": {
"value": "wiiamjos",
"fuzziness": "AUTO"
}
}
}
}

Not in comment. Put this in your post.

added in post too.

Yes. That will do.

Elasticsearch uses Levenshtein Edit Distance algorithm by default in fuzzy query. The maximum allowed Levenshtein Edit Distance is 2 in Elasticsearch because of the performance consideration and it's limitted by Lucene. So, you can match max two fuzzines with the following options.

Changing a character (box → fox)
Removing a character (black → lack)
Inserting a character (sic → sick)
Transposing two adjacent characters (act → cat)

Note: With Suggester search you can use damerau_levenshtein, levenshtein, or jaro_winkler string_distance algorithms but the max_edits, aka max edit distance, is 2.

So, it's not possible to search wiiamjos and find WilliamJones with fuzzy search in Elasticsearch.

Workarounds:

Find an ML model for phonetic search, implement into Elasticsearch, use kNN query for search.
Use another technology
Check the tilores.io looks interesting.

References:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html
https://tilores.io/jaro-similarity-algorithm-online-tool?t1=WilliamJones&t2=wiiamjos


